# How to serve react app using quarkus dev server?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, quarkus

I am working on a Quarkus microservice that serves a React frontend in addition to the REST API it provides. I have followed the available resources on this topic, which are a blog post and a book written by the same author:

1. https://blog.marcnuri.com/react-quarkus-integration-using-maven
2. And the book written by the same author: https://www.packtpub.com/product/full-stack-quarkus-and-react/9781800562738

Currently, the build using Maven works fine, and when I start the Quarkus app either with mvn quarkus:dev or by packaging and running the jar, the frontend pages are displayed correctly at http://localhost:8080. However, the pages seem to be static; For example, **a hook that should be called when the app starts or is refreshed doesn't get called**.

```
    useEffect(() => async () => {
        const items = await getAllItems();
        setItems(items);
    }, []);
```

When I start the npm server manually, everything works as expected.

I also use routes and React context to manage the app state:

```
        <AppContext > 
            <Routes>
                <Route path='/home' element={<Home />}></Route>
                <Route path='/policies' element={<Policies />}></Route>
                <Route path='/' element={<Navigate to="/home" />} />
            </Routes>
        </AppContext>
```

I've used exactly the same approach as described in the book and in this tutorial to forward the frontend pages, by creating a rest endpoint which will find the the matching files and send it back as a response.

I'd like to hear some suggestions how to solve this issue.

Thank you!

I attempted to follow both this tutorial and other similar ones, with the expectation that the frontend will be hosted on the Quarkus server and function seamlessly as if it were on a seperate node server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Quinoa](https://quarkiverse.github.io/quarkiverse-docs/quarkus-quinoa/dev/) may be what you're looking for, to get everthing super-live. It gives a nice bridge between the jaavascript side and the java side, including hot reload of everything in dev mode.

You can make a boilerplate project using

```
quarkus create app quinoa-app -x=io.quarkiverse.quinoa:quarkus-quinoa
```

Then start the live-coding with

```
quarkus dev
```

If you navigate to http://0.0.0.0:8080/quinoa.html you should see the Quinoa welcome page. Once you've confirmed things are working, you can copy in your js project into `src/main/webui`.

If you make sure that your `application.properties` has

```
quarkus.quinoa.dev-server.port=3000
```

you can access the js app on http://localhost:8000, and requests are proxied through to the javascript server.

Comment: Thank you! It seems my issue is not related to the quarkus deployment, but this Quinoa extension does makes life easier.